# TexStudio Show FIles in structure

Tags: texstudio

I want to see files of the same directory in the structure panel.
For example, if I have two file I have in TexStudio :
[image]

But unlike overleaf, I dont see a_other_document.tex in structure :

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: Which version of `texstudio` do you use?

Comment: It's the 3.1.2,

Comment: Perhaps you can post it to https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues.

Comment: Looks like someone already asked for it on GitHub: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/639